# How to parse or extract data from "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]" object in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, mvp

I'm writing a console application that displays all the user's license information in my tenant. When I tried to print, It's printing like "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]". How to parse data from it using c#?

```
     foreach (PSObject result in PS.Invoke())
            {
                foreach (var member in result.Members)
                {
                     if (member.Name == "Licenses")
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine(member.Value);
                    }
                };
            }
```

Comment: What type is member.Value? That error message suggests it's a list of `UserLicense` objects, therefore you need to manually output the individual properties yourself.

Comment: It's a PSObject which have MSoluser details, I wanna parse to get the data . System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense] Licenses {get;set;} , this is what it returns when I display the user Licenses @Neil

Answer (score 1):

[`` List`1 `` (or `List<T>` if you will)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) implements `IEnumerable`, so an extra `foreach` loop to iterate through the values will do:

```
foreach (PSObject result in PS.Invoke())
{
    foreach (var member in result.Members)
    {
        if (member.Name == "Licenses")
        {
            foreach (var license in member.Value)
            {
                // license is now an individual `UserLicense` object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error - CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator' framework C:\Users\Nithish\source\repos\framework\Program.cs 47 Active

Comment: I got this error while using another foreach to iterate through the object